# Parse error posting data with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, post

I am attempting to `POST` data to an API using PHP and cURL like so:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.api.myAPIsite.com/values?api_key=MyAPIKey");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    "configuration"=> { 
         "vehicleId"=> 382245, 
         "vehicleOptionIds"=> [5154080] 
    }, 
    "mileage"=> 100000, 
    "zipCode"=> "02101", 
    "valuationDate"=> "2019-04-08T23:59:21.803Z" 
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

However, the log says parse error had occurred. What would the correct syntax be to solve this?

Log details:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/78ds6f76f8fds6f/public_html/desktop/values.php on line 11
```

Comment: Any parse error details in the logs ?

Comment: I updated the question to show the log details, says unexpected '{' on line 11 which is the line with "configuration" => {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (incorrectly) using JavaScript's object notation instead of PHP's array notation inside your `'configuration'` array key, to fix this, simply change your `$data` array to the following:

```
$data = array(
    "configuration"=> [
         "vehicleId"=> 382245,
         "vehicleOptionIds"=> [5154080]
    ],
    "mileage"=> 100000,
    "zipCode"=> "02101",
    "valuationDate"=> "2019-04-08T23:59:21.803Z"
);
```

Comment: FYI ...you used right object syntax from javascript but not work in php ;)